# UIWebView load https but quick change it to http

Tags: https, uiwebview

I use UIWebview to load https url, mostly https urls work normal in my app, but some urls make the UIWebview delegate `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` called twice.

First time, the request parameter has the right https url. Second time, the url  in request parameter change to http scheme, this cause the url load failed with error 1022: "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection."

I use Charles to see the network, can not see the https request, means not 320 reqeust, not see the http request either, because the request is block by iOS system, so failed with 1022 code

It's so weird, what the problem is!!!
The https url can be load normal in safari or chrome. I create a new project with only the webview load the https url，It's OK

Comment: Did you find solution for this issue?